# How can I reduce iterations in for loop that takes to much time for execution?

Tags: java, for-loop

Here, I am finding number of perfect square numbers in given range.

But I am dealing with 'for' loop execution that takes much time for execution.

The index/key traverses from two numbers, lets say A to B, and does some operation in for loop.

The problem arises when there's large difference between A and B (e.g. A = 2 & B = 100000)

Can u suggest how can I reduce or optimize the execution time?

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int A = in.nextInt();
        int B = in.nextInt();

        int cnt = 0;
        for(int number =A ; number<= B; number++){
        int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number);
              if(sqrt*sqrt == number) {
                    cnt++;
                }
        }
        System.out.println(cnt);
```

Or is it because of Math class operations that takes too much time to execute?

Can you suggest any alternate approach to find the square numbers between given range?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use [this](http://burningmath.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-check-if-number-is-perfect-square.html) to check perfect squares faster

Comment: @Natecat: Your link appears to be removed. It gives a 404.

Comment: @STaefi Not on my end, strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an alternate way to find the count of perfect square numbers between given range.

This can be simply achieve by using Math.floor and Math.ceil operations.

```
Math.floor(Math.sqrt(B)) -  Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(A)) + 1
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through each number in the range and figuring out if its a perfect square, I would suggest the below

`Find a square root of the start number and find the integer part of it.`

Lets say start number is 5. So integer part of the square root will be 2.

`Now do the same for the range end number`

Lets say end range was 1000, so the integer part of its square root would be 31. Now iterate from 2+1 to 31 and keep printing its square. That would give you the perfect squares between the given range.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `if(sqrt * sqrt == number)` you could also check whether the double returned by `Math.srt(number)` is a integer. The algorithm would than become as follows:

```
for(int number =A ; number<= B; number++){
    if((Math.sqrt(number) % 1) == 0) {
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

*Note:* Haven't tried the code myself so might not work as I expect.

Regarding the question on how you can improve the performance. The checking on whether the number is perfect could be done in parallel by executing per number a task. The access to the counter has to be synchronized than, (to be on the safe side).